# Creating an invite and send it to an user that is not in your server/guild

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a site where users register. In the registration process, I ask them to provide their discord user to let them access a discord community we own.

Is it possible to create an invite for my guild/channel and send it to a discord user using discord.js? I need this invite to be unique and limited to one use. So, I need to create a new one everytime a user registers at the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create a unique invite, but you cannot send it to the user inside Discord, you'll need to show the link in your webpage: bots cannot message users that are not in a mutual guild, to prevent spamming.

To create an invite you can use the [`GuildChannel.createInvite()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=createInvite) method:

```
let newInvite = await channel.createInvite({
  maxUses: 1, // After one use it will be void
  unique: true, // That tells the bot not to use an existing invite so that this will be unique
  maxAge: 86400 // By default invites last 24 hours. If you want to change that, modify this (0 = lasts forever, time in seconds)
});
```