# Is there a way I can join a discord server, through its ID, My bot is already in the server

Tags: discord, discord.js

My bot is in some servers that I'm not in, and I want to join those servers with the help of my bot.

I tried a lot of different code, but none of them seemed to work for me. I found a question that was similar to mine but it was for discord.py (python).

My bot is coded in Discord.JS.
h
I want to able to do +create (ID) and then it returns with that servers invite link.

ex: +create 2320329132 | Return: discord.gg/Ud9283

sorry my english isnt good. thank you if you can help me :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54463473/creating-an-invite-and-send-it-to-an-user-that-is-not-in-your-server-guild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let guild = client.guilds.cache.get(args[0]);
let channel = guild.channels.cache.filter(ch => ch.type === "text");
channel.first().createInvite({ maxUsers: 1, maxAge: 0, unique: true})
.then(invite => message.channel.send(`https://discord.gg/${invite.code}`));
```

I am assuming that you defined `args` and `client` already. `guild` stores the server you provided by its ID. `channel` filters every text channel and stores it. Then we take the first found text channel by using `channel.first()` and create an invite by using [.createInvite()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=createInvite) (because you only can create an invite to a channel). After that we use `.then` to get the invite code and send the full link to the current text channel.